# can we define angular dependencies in app.controller level rather then in app.module level?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm following this example for  ui.grid
site: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/203_pinning

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning']);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {};
```

I'm using app.js file to define my Common dependencies using in all controllers etc. (whole app)

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["ngResource", "ui.router", "ngTouch", "ui.grid", "'ui.grid.pinning'"]);
```

As you can see "ui.grid" and "ui.grid.pinning" is defined in application or module level. all my controllers/services can use it.

**Question:**
Is there a way to define these 2 dependencies in controller level? like below, because I'm not going to use it in other controllers/pages....
now I get squeeze underlines in my editor with code below, I assume it's because of the dots(.). it says { expected....

```
 app.controller("empController", ['$scope',  
 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning',
             function ($scope, ui.grid, ui.grid.pinning) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the explicit `$injector` in your controller.

```
app.controller("empController", function empController($scope, ui.grid, ui.grid.pinning){
    empController.inject = ['$scope','ui.grid','ui.grid.pinning'];
}
```

Comment: I change as you proposed, it still complains (squeeze line) under first ui.grid it shows in tooltip "error: Expectd { " and in first ui.grid.pinning it shows in tooltip: "Expected ;".... I'm thinking I'm using Visual Studio as Editor, is it the Visual Studio editor which doesn't accept while it should be correct? any idea?

Comment: it's hard to say, exactly; the hinting system built in to visual studio is pretty bare and doesn't always understand JavaScript syntax.  If you don't have it, I would HIGHLY recommend Web Essentials for Visual Studio... it uses a much clearer version of JSHint.  Bear in mind, JavaScript is not a compiled language, so the suggestion lines are merely that, suggestions. Also, newer versions of Visual Studio are more aware of JavaScript....  http://vswebessentials.com/

Comment: thank you so much for the info, i think you advised me on right path which was helpful.